# Letting a method of an Enum class through proguard

Tags: java, android, enums, proguard

I am getting this error in my Console:

```
 [java] Warning: com.mopub.mraid.PostitialMraidWebViewClient: can't find referenced method 'com.mopub.mraid.MraidJavascriptCommand fromJavascriptString(java.lang.String)' in class com.mopub.mraid.MraidJavascriptCommand
```

I am trying to let the class and method through proguard but I am not having any success. I think the way to describe it would be a method inside an enum class?  I'm not really sure exactly.

This is the class:

```
package com.mopub.mraid;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

public enum MraidJavascriptCommand {
    CLOSE("close"),
    EXPAND("expand") {
        @Override
        boolean requiresClick(@NonNull final PlacementType placementType) {
            return placementType == PlacementType.INLINE;
        }
    },
    USE_CUSTOM_CLOSE("usecustomclose"),
    OPEN("open") {
        @Override
        boolean requiresClick(@NonNull final PlacementType placementType) {
            return true;
        }
    },
    RESIZE("resize") {
        @Override
        boolean requiresClick(@NonNull final PlacementType placementType) {
            return true;
        }
    },
    SET_ORIENTATION_PROPERTIES("setOrientationProperties"),
    PLAY_VIDEO("playVideo") {
        @Override
        boolean requiresClick(@NonNull final PlacementType placementType) {
            return placementType == PlacementType.INLINE;
        }
    },
    STORE_PICTURE("storePicture") {
        @Override
        boolean requiresClick(@NonNull final PlacementType placementType) {
            return true;
        }
    },
    CREATE_CALENDAR_EVENT("createCalendarEvent") {
        @Override
        boolean requiresClick(@NonNull final PlacementType placementType) {
            return true;
        }
    },
    UNSPECIFIED("");

@NonNull private final String mJavascriptString;

MraidJavascriptCommand(@NonNull String javascriptString) {
    mJavascriptString = javascriptString;
}

static MraidJavascriptCommand fromJavascriptString(@NonNull String string) {
    for (MraidJavascriptCommand command : MraidJavascriptCommand.values()) {
        if (command.mJavascriptString.equals(string)) {
            return command;
        }
    }

    return UNSPECIFIED;
}

String toJavascriptString() {
    return mJavascriptString;
}

boolean requiresClick(@NonNull PlacementType placementType) {
    return false;
}
}
```

I have tried a few different ways of writing this out, but nothing seems to work for me:

```
 -keep class com.mopub.mraid.MraidJavascriptCommand {
    *;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method that is missing does seem to be present in the source code that you show. Chances are that the input that is passed to ProGuard contains an older compiled version of the class, without the method. You should start with a clean build, check the input, and also see if the ProGuard log contains any warnings about duplicate classes.